# How to create 'blocked tails' using :after?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry, I'm not quite sure what these would be called. I have a module that when hovers, displays another box with information. I would like these to be connected with an angled rectangle(or tail) to show that they are meant to go together.

Similar to this:
[image]

I originally have tried to do it with a rotated rectangle and an :after element, but that did not work very well for responsive and was wondering what you guys thought.

I built the list like this:

```
<div class="pp-left">
<ul>
<li class="targ">Target</li>
<li class="conn">Connect</li>
<li class="conv">Convert</li>
<li class="opti">Optimize</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Followed by the 'pop ups' with respective CSS Classes:

```
<div class="pp-right">
   <div class="target-popup popup" style="display: none;">
      <p>Build data-rich supporter profiles, segmenting them, and targeting them with one-to-one communications. Create custom groups to segment constituents by activities, interests, giving level, location, etc and set list segmentation conditions that auto-populate and refresh groups daily.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I am handling the hovers/show/hide with this type of function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.target-popup').show();
    $('.targ, .target-popup').hover(function() {
            $('.target-popup').show();
        },
        function() {
            $('.target-popup').hide();
        });
});
```

Here is my workable [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4p1452j/).

Comment: My first idea would be to use the transform: skewY(); function (in combination with :after) as well. Looking at caniuse.com this has good browser support. Could you elaborate a bit the issues you had with responsiveness?

Comment: When scaling down (since they had to be `absolute` positioned) they would run into each other or gain extra margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, a pseudo-element and a transform...in this case a `skewY` and an adjustment to the `transform-origin`.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  background: darkred;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewY(25deg)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I thought this was a great answer. But I am really surprised to see it's not working in Safari Mobile. Is that because I am (still) using iOS7... or is it because Safari Mobile hasn't yet added support for CSS transforms without the -webkit- proprietary extension?

Comment: I generally leave the prefixes out of code on SO. That just bloats the example. You would have to prefix for Safari.

Comment: Ah! I always forget about `transform-origin` I'm going to select this one as correct example since it doesn't require adding any classes. Thanks for the help Paulie_D!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Paulie_D. I have modified HTML/CSS and included a div with class "indicator". Here is the respective code

```
div.indicator {
   background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
 }

 div.indicator::after {
   background: darkred none repeat scroll 0 0;
   content: "";
   height: 42px;
   left: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   transform: skewY(25deg);
   transform-origin: left top 0;
   width: 15px;
 }
```

and you can see the demo in https://jsfiddle.net/q0qzLh74/

I have not modified the jQuery. Each li has the div with class "indicator". So jQuery need to be changed to show/hide accordingly.

Comment: I have used ShapesOfCSS. I have tried doing it with a rectangle that was tilted with `transform:rotate(x)` but still run into the same issue.